# Can't update fragment with API call listener

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm making a few API calls and I would like to have a progress animation in my home fragment of my Android App (for testing I simply update text).
I have implemented it so that the fragment is a listener for these API calls and when I `Log.d()` inside the `onEventAPIProgressChanged()` method the right numbers are printed, but every time I try to change the text of the fragment it tells me that my view is null.

So I thought okay so maybe my fragment is not yet initialized, before the first `onEventAPIProgressChanged()` is called, but I when I just change the text on initialisation of the fragment to "loading..." I can clearly see that the fragment (and therefore also the view) is already initialized and in fact not null.

Here is my `HomeFragment`:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements EventAPIListener {

//I skipped some unrelated code here

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.determinateBar);
        barText = view.findViewById(R.id.barText);
        return view;
    }

    private View fragmentView;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        fragmentView = view;

        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.determinateBar);
        barText = view.findViewById(R.id.barText);
        barText.setText("loading...");
        Log.d("PROGRESS","View created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onEventAPIProgressChanged(int currentItem, int maxItems) {
        Log.d("PROGRESS", currentItem + " / " + maxItems);
        if (fragmentView == null) {
            Log.d("PROGRESS", "VIEW NULL");
            return;
        }

        TextView localBarText = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.barText);
        if (localBarText != null) {
            localBarText.setText(currentItem + " / " + maxItems);
        }
    }
}
```

The console returns first "View created" and then the correct API call number and "VIEW NULL".
And the text is changed immediately to "loading..." but the `fragmentView` (I also tried it with simply the view) never becomes not null :(

I expected it to change my Text - and even if the fragment takes a few seconds to initialise (which it seemingly does not) at least for later API calls `fragmentView` should not be null.

Edit:
`onEventAPIProgressChanged()` is part of the `EventAPIListener` and gets called in my API-Request when one API Request is finished:

```
public void onEventAPIProgressChanged(int currentItem, int maxItems) {
        if(registeredListeners.size() < 1) {return;}
        for(EventAPIListener listener:registeredListeners) {
            listener.onEventAPIProgressChanged(currentItem, maxItems);
        }
    }

  public void makeVolleyRequest(String apiUrl, boolean lastCall, int callID, String artistDisplayName) {
        request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, apiUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try { //Filters the JSON responses for actual events
                    Log.d("Volley", "TM-" + callID + " received");
                    onEventAPIProgressChanged(callID, artistList.size());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {...}
```

Comment: Show how `fragmentView` is declared and used. Show how `onEventAPIProgressChanged` is called on the fragment.

Comment: fragmentView is essentially just view (I just tested if it would help to declare it - in retrospective kinda stupid) and its declared right above onViewCreated(). I edited my question for clarification on the `onEventAPIProgressChanged()`

Comment: How and when is the fragment registered as the api listener?